# A characterization of continuous periodic sets

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Consider the space $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ of functions from the set of real numbers to the set of real numbers. A real number $r$ is said to be a period of a given function $f$ iff for all real numbers $x$, $f(x+r)=f(x)$. I define a periodic set to be the set of periods of a given function. I define a continuous periodic set to be the set of periods of a given continuous function. It is easy to show that $\mathbb{R}$ itself and also $r * \mathbb{Z}$ are continuous periodic sets, where the latter denotes the product of the real number $r$ with the set of integers. Is the converse true? That is, is every continuous periodic set either $\mathbb{R}$ or $r * \mathbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is yes. Let $f \in C(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ be periodic and not constant. Then there is a minimal positive period $r> 0$. Otherwise there would be a sequence of positive periods $(r_n)$ with $r_n \to 0$. Then
$f(\mathbb{R}) \subseteq f([0,r_n])$ for all $n$ and as $f$ is continuous ist would be constant $f(0)$, a contradiction. Now let $s$ be any period, w.l.o.g. $s>0$. Then $r\le s$. We show that $s=mr$ for some $m \in  \mathbb{N}$: Otherwise
$$
\exists m \in \mathbb{N}: mr < s < (m+1)r. 
$$
Then $0<s-mr<r$, ans since $s-mr$ is a positive period this contradicts the minimality of $r$. Thus any positive period is in $r \ast\mathbb{N}$ and so the set of all periods is  $r \ast\mathbb{Z}$.